# Yii2: How to delete with relation 3 table on Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have the following tables and I want to click delete at `Pak` button which can delete all 3 tables relations.

How can I achieve that?

```
table Pak : id_pak, pak_name/////
table Church : id_church, church_name, id_pak/////
table Member : id_member, name_member, id_church////

public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->findModel($id);
    $select = Church::find()
            ->select('church_name')
            ->where(['id_pak' => $id])
            ->all();

    $a3 = Church::find()
        ->select('id_church')
        ->where(['id_pak' => $id])
        ->all();

    $select2 = Member::find()
            ->select('member_name')
            ->where(['id_church'=> $a3])
            ->all();
    Church::find()->where(['id_pak' => $id])->one()->delete();
    Pak::find()->where(['id_pak' =>$id])->one()->delete();
    Member::find()->where(['id_church'=> $a3])->one()->delete();
    return $this->redirect(['index','select'=>$select,'select2'=>$select2]);
}
```

Comment: are you using `innoDB` engine with constraints defined?

Answer (score 0):

### Using Constraints with innoDB Engine

If you are using InnoDB and have added the constraints `on delete cascade` correctly and defined the respective relations in the models you don't need to worry about the related records in the other tables you just need to find the model in the `Pak` and delete it.

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}

protected function findModel( $id ) {
    if ( ($model = Pak::findOne ( $id )) !== null ) {
        return $model;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException ( 'The requested page does not exist.' );
}
```

### Removing Manually

Or if you are not using innoDB or not using constraints for any reason then you can override the `beforeDelete()` in the ActiveRecord Model for `Pak` and remove all the child rows for the `Pak` Model in the `Church` and override `beforeDelete()` inside the `Church` to delete all child rows in `Member` model and return true from there to continue deleting the actual record in the `Pak` model

I assume that you have the following relations defined in the `Pak` model

```
public function getChurch(){
    return $this->hasOne(Church::className(), ['id_pak'=>'id_pak']);
}
```

and the following inside the `Church` model

```
public function getMember(){
    return $this->hasOne(Member::className(),['id_church'=>'id_church']);
}
```

Then override the `beforeDelete()` in the `Pak` model

```
public function beforeDelete() {
    $this->church->delete();
    return parent::beforeDelete ();
}
```

and override the `beforeDelete()` in the `Church` Model

```
public function beforeDelete() {
    $this->member->delete();
    return parent::beforeDelete ();
}
```

and in your `actionDelete()` just find the model and call delete

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

There is also a nice article on implementing `recursiveDelete()` method in a parent model [`here`](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/437/handling-recursive-deletion-in-yii).

Comment: I cannot delete 3 tables. Get Error Trying to get property 'member' of non-object at  $memberModel->delete();   Which I add function get member at Church model and add function get church at Pak Model. But Cannot found member. How can I achieve it?  Help me please

Comment: are you sure that the value you are trying to delete in Pak has the foreign key in the church and the value ot the church has a valid foreign key in the Member model?

Comment: I suggest to delete `Member` inside of `Church::beforeDelete()` - every AR should be responsible for deleting its own children.

Comment: hmm, thats more better i agree @rob006

Answer (score 0):

Following code may help you to solve your problem.

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $select = Church::find()
            ->select('church_name')
            ->where(['id_pak' => $id])
            ->all();

    $a3 = Church::find()
        ->select('id_church')
        ->where(['id_pak' => $id])
        ->all();

    $select2 = Member::find()
            ->select('member_name')
            ->where(['id_church'=> $a3])
            ->all();

    // ---------- start ---------------
    $park = Park::find()->where(['id_pak' => $id])->one();
    if ( $park->delete() ){
        Pak::deleteAll('id_pak = :id', [':id' => $id]);
        foreach ($a3 as $value) {
            Member::deleteAll('id_church = :id', [':id' => $value->id_church ]);
        }
    }
    // ---------- end ---------------

    return $this->redirect(['index','select'=>$select,'select2'=>$select2]);
}
```